# Nodejs deployment error to Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment

I have a problem to deploy my Node app to Heroku, I'm specified node and npm version, set procfile, but having problem again, can anyone help me where I'm wrong.

Here is error log.

```
-----> Node.js app detected
-----> Creating runtime environment

       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  6.7.0
       engines.npm (package.json):   3.10.3

       Resolving node version 6.7.0...
       Downloading and installing node 6.7.0...
       npm 3.10.3 already installed with node
-----> Restoring cache
       Skipping cache restore (not-found)
-----> Building dependencies
       Prebuild detected (node_modules already exists)
       Rebuilding any native modules

       > bcrypt@1.0.3 install /tmp/build_41d193481a84256234156f8c6f5f2420/goransgit-Random-Movie-ec7e060/node_modules/bcrypt
       > node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

       sh: 1: node-pre-gyp: Permission denied

       npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-133-generic
       npm ERR! argv "/tmp/build_41d193481a84256234156f8c6f5f2420/goransgit-Random-Movie-ec7e060/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/tmp/build_41d193481a84256234156f8c6f5f2420/goransgit-Random-Movie-ec7e060/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "rebuild"
       npm ERR! node v6.7.0
       npm ERR! npm  v3.10.3
       npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
       npm ERR! bcrypt@1.0.3 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
       npm ERR! Exit status 126
       npm ERR!
       npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@1.0.3 install script 'node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build'.
       npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
       npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the bcrypt package,
       npm ERR! not with npm itself.
       npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
       npm ERR!     node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
       npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
       npm ERR!     npm bugs bcrypt
       npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
       npm ERR!     npm owner ls bcrypt
       npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

       npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
       npm ERR!     /tmp/build_41d193481a84256234156f8c6f5f2420/goransgit-Random-Movie-ec7e060/npm-debug.log
-----> Build failed

       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys

       Some possible problems:

       - node_modules checked into source control
       https://blog.heroku.com/node-habits-2016#9-only-git-the-important-bits

       Love,
       Heroku

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
 !     Push failed
```

Here is my package.json file with all neccecary depedencies.

```
{
  "name": "Node app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",

  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  },

  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",

  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^1.0.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "express-session": "^1.15.6",
    "express-validator": "^4.2.1",
    "form-validate": "0.0.7",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "validator": "^9.1.1"
  },

  "engines" : {
    "node" : "6.7.0",
    "npm" : "3.10.3"
  }
}
```

If anyone could help me, thanks.

DO NOT MIND LOREM IPSUM BELOW
Nostrud reprehenderit sed amet enim nulla pariatur ut dolore officia duis fugiat elit excepteur in nostrud duis irure in ut cillum sunt sunt ut incididunt in culpa in veniam adipisicing aliquip exercitation enim dolore exercitation mollit eu sunt irure excepteur magna mollit esse non dolor fugiat consequat ex incididunt laboris adipisicing culpa aliquip eu in dolor do excepteur quis aliquip enim eu ut dolor ex culpa ullamco deserunt in et deserunt in sit occaecat ex do dolor do dolore veniam est elit elit minim cupidatat mollit nisi sint non adipisicing cillum ullamco reprehenderit do nisi nulla commodo aute incididunt anim eu tempor incididunt sunt cupidatat velit dolor culpa sit est elit veniam dolor irure in irure minim dolor sit nisi est pariatur officia esse aliquip ex enim sint cupidatat eu excepteur laborum mollit ut ullamco cillum cillum veniam qui laboris excepteur ex sed commodo magna adipisicing do culpa pariatur sed reprehenderit eu deserunt quis adipisicing nisi sunt ad ad dolore incididunt dolor sint sint et laborum ea magna ea incididunt non esse non sunt sint est ad veniam ullamco ad dolor sint ut aliqua incididunt ullamco non nulla proident reprehenderit anim esse non dolor sint pariatur aliqua excepteur irure non aute sed ut veniam laboris ad occaecat adipisicing proident laboris occaecat laborum laboris culpa in incididunt labore in sed tempor dolore in quis reprehenderit enim mollit dolor esse.

Answer (score 0):

Some possible problems:
 - node_modules checked into source control

Put node_modules inside your .gitignore file. This directory should not be in a git repository.

Then remove the directory from git:

```
git rm -r node_modules
git commit -m "Remove node_modules directory"
```

Then push to Heroku

I suggest using this gitignore file for Node.js projects:
https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Node.gitignore

Comment: Please ask these questions in the comments. Answers should be complete solutions.

Comment: "You must have 50 reputation to comment", so I can't ask questions in the comments.